# User defined rules for categorizing data

Tags: javascript

Suppose we have three distinct categories, buy hold sell

We want to be able to pass a "stock" object array into a function, where the objects have attributes, e.g.

```
var stocks = [  
{ticker: BACON, industry: food , isTech: true, isGreen: false, isIntl = true, is52weekHigh: true},
{ticker: PEE, industry: plumbing, isTech: true, isGreen: true, isIntl = true,    is52weekHigh: false},
{ticker: BEER, industry: beverage, isTech: true, isGreen: true, isIntl = true,    is52weekHigh: true},
```

where the function should apply rules that are set by user to categorize each stock into one of the three categories, buy hold sell.

Rules are simple: This and that, this or that, this but not that.

E.g.
Buy: 
criteria 1: (isTech = true and isIntl = true and ticker not equal to PEE)
or 
criteria 2:  (industry = beverage or industry = food)

Not really sure how to approach it! any help is appreciated.

Comment: Are users gonna actually write the rules somehow like in  criteria 1 ex.?

Comment: no they will use UI controls to build the logic/model

Comment: Can you edit the question and post these controls' html too if they are ready?

Comment: Are BACON, food etc variables already assigned or should they be strings?

Answer (score 0):

If you are building the logic from a restricted UI then using eval should be safe.

I have run the following in the Scratchpad in Firefox.

NOTE:- use of strings rather than variables for BACON, food etc in each object and need to replace = with : after isIntl

```
   var stocks = [  
        {ticker: 'BACON', industry: 'food' , isTech: true, isGreen: false, isIntl : true, is52weekHigh: true},
        {ticker: 'PEE', industry: 'plumbing', isTech: true, isGreen: true, isIntl :true,    is52weekHigh: false},
        {ticker: 'BEER', industry: 'beverage', isTech: true, isGreen: true, isIntl : true,    is52weekHigh: true}
    ]

    for(var i=0;i<stocks.length;i++) {
        stock=stocks[i];
        console.log(eval((stock['isTech'] && stock['isIntl'] && stock['ticker'] != 'PEE') || (stock['industry']=='beverage' || stock['industry']=='food')));
    }
```